# Gwtp NullpointerException- annotation

Tags: java, gwt, annotations, gwtp

I am trying to implement a mobileweb app using Gwtp. **I have the desktop and tablet view working but i get an error for mobile view.** I am binding 3 different presenters for desktop, mobile and tablet view. So it will be a different landing page on different devices. I need different landing page functionality on different devices. The first presenter on a tablet will be a list of tasks, but on a mobile the user has to login first to see the list of tasks. Also, some of the presenters will be shared by a tablet and mobile view.

**MobileModule**-

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(DefaultPlace.class).to(NameTokens.login);

bindPresenter(LoginPresenter.class, LoginPresenter.MyView.class,
                LoginView.class, LoginPresenter.MyProxy.class);

bindPresenter(MainListTabletPresenter.class,
    MainListTabletPresenter.MyView.class, MainListMobileView.class,
            MainListTabletPresenter.MyProxy.class);
```

**TabletModule**-

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(DefaultPlace.class).to(NameTokens.mainList);

bindPresenter(MainListTabletPresenter.class,
            MainListTabletPresenter.MyView.class, MainListTabletView.class,
            MainListTabletPresenter.MyProxy.class);

bindPresenter(LoginPresenter.class, LoginPresenter.MyView.class,
        LoginView.class, LoginPresenter.MyProxy.class);
```

Any ideas why i would get the following (`NullpointerException` about annotations), when i run the application? I think i have the annotations correct for the `LoginPresenter`.

```
(MainPageEntryPoint.java:83) 2012-08-27 18:43:54,360 [ERROR] e: com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireEvent(HistoryImpl.java:75)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.fire(ValueChangeEvent.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireHistoryChangedImpl(HistoryImpl.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.fireCurrentHistoryState(History.java:121)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.revealCurrentPlace(PlaceManagerImpl.java:310)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.MainPageEntryPoint.revealCurrentPlace(MainPageEntryPoint.java:114)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.MainPageEntryPoint.onModuleLoad2(MainPageEntryPoint.java:68)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.MainPageEntryPoint$1.execute(MainPageEntryPoint.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:228)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushPostEventPumpCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:388)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Flusher.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:203)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEventFromSource(SimpleEventBus.java:96)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.fireEvent(PlaceManagerImpl.java:146)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.doRevealPlace(PlaceManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.revealPlace(PlaceManagerImpl.java:339)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.place.ClientPlaceManager.revealDefaultPlace(ClientPlaceManager.java:27)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceManagerImpl.onValueChange(PlaceManagerImpl.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:128)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    ... 39 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.view.mobile.LoginView.<init>(LoginView.java:54)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.gin.MobileGinjectorImpl.com$happs$curveapp$client$view$mobile$LoginView_LoginView_methodInjection(MobileGinjectorImpl.java:1749)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.gin.MobileGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$happs$curveapp$client$view$mobile$LoginView$_annotation$$none$$(MobileGinjectorImpl.java:1753)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.gin.MobileGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$happs$curveapp$client$view$mobile$LoginView$_annotation$$none$$(MobileGinjectorImpl.java:1767)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.gin.MobileGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$happs$curveapp$client$presenter$LoginPresenter$MyView$_annotation$$none$$(MobileGinjectorImpl.java:231)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.gin.MobileGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$happs$curveapp$client$presenter$LoginPresenter$MyView$_annotation$$none$$(MobileGinjectorImpl.java:240)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.gin.MobileGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$happs$curveapp$client$presenter$LoginPresenter$_annotation$$none$$(MobileGinjectorImpl.java:299)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.gin.MobileGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$happs$curveapp$client$presenter$LoginPresenter$_annotation$$none$$(MobileGinjectorImpl.java:313)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.gin.MobileGinjectorImpl.access$0(MobileGinjectorImpl.java:311)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.gin.MobileGinjectorImpl$1$1.onSuccess(MobileGinjectorImpl.java:254)

    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.runAsync(GWT.java:255)
    at com.happs.curveapp.client.gin.MobileGinjectorImpl$1.get(MobileGinjectorImpl.java:252)
    at com.gwtplatform.common.client.CodeSplitProvider.get(CodeSplitProvider.java:48)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyImpl.getPresenter(ProxyImpl.java:46)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract.handleRequest(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:193)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract.access$0(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:192)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlaceAbstract$1.onPlaceRequest(ProxyPlaceAbstract.java:143)
at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceRequestInternalEvent.dispatch(PlaceRequestInternalEvent.java:134)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.PlaceRequestInternalEvent.dispatch(PlaceRequestInternalEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: What's the code at line 54 of LoginView?

Comment: Ok i asked a dumb question . I was accessing a textbox before a createandbind(). NullPointerExceptoion- it should have been self explanatory. Why do i think i messed something in gwtp than just my java code?   54: txtUsername.setAutoCapitalize(false);
55: widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);